# Solve this specific large sparse system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, block-matrices, sparse-matrices

I want to solve the system $Ax = b$ where $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb R^n$ with $n \approx 10^6$. If $A$ would be a fully dense matrix this would be hopeless of course but luckily the matrix is sparse and highly structured.

The matrix $A$ can be written as

\begin{align}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
B_0 & B_1 &     &     &     \\
    & C_1 & B_2 &     &     \\
    &     & C_2 & B_3 &     \\
    &     &     & C_3 & B_4 \\
D   &     &     &     & C_4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

where $B_i$ are upper triangular matrices, $C_i$ are diagonal with each entry being equal to $-1$, and $D$ is a square matrix. The figure below provides a schematic overview of $A$ where every possibly nonzero entry is green and all zeroes are gray.

The upper triangular matrices $B_i$ have approximately the same structure but do not necessarily have the same entry values. The submatrices $B_i$, $C_i$, and $D$ typically have dimension $m\times m$ with $m \approx 10^5$.

I don't know whether it is useful, but we also know for all non-zeroes with $i \neq j$ that $a_{ij} \in (0, 1]$ and the entries on the diagonal equal $-1$ except for the part that overlaps with $B_0$, i.e., we have $C_i = -I$.

Note that the corresponding system $(A + I)y = b$, where $I$ is an identity matrix, is relatively easy to solve as the submatrices $C_i$ become null matrices. Then we can first solve $D \hat x = \hat b$ where $\hat x$ and $\hat b$ are the last entries of $x$ and $b$. Next, we can iteratively solve the triangular matrices one by one starting with the one closest to the bottom. Maybe we can use the solution $y$ (or a transformation of $y$) as an initial solution for $x$ for an iterative approach.

Is there a better way to solve this system compared to naively feeding the system to a solver such as Matlab or LAPACK?

EDIT 1: Green entries indicate a *possibly* positive value. However, for the square at the bottom, around half of the entries are expected to be zero.

EDIT 2: Given the enormous size of this problem, approximate methods are also more than welcome.

[image: Schematic overview of matrix A]

Comment: If I am right, you can decompose in blocks where the blocks are diagonal or quasi-triangular (presumably, there remains a single element of the bottom left corner). Plus the full block.

Comment: You can get rid of the corner elements by decomposing in blocks and single rows/columns to isolate them. The benefit is that the inverses of the pure triangular matrices are easily obtained. I guess that the resolution can be virtually reduced to that of the full square, though the latter is still huge.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for your comments. Could you elaborate a bit more on the decomposition you propose in an answer?

Comment: Are your $B_k, k>0$ truly triangular ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes $B_k, k \geq 0$ (indeed also $B_0$) are all upper triangular matrices.

Comment: Softwarewise I would point out that R has a number of packages specifically for sparse matrices that allow solving linear problems with methods suitable for sparse matrices. I don't know whether Matlab or LAPACK do that as well, but if not using software with in-built methods for sparse matrices may already be sufficient for your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key is the fact that $C_i = - I$, i.e., the appropriately size identity matrix is trivially nonsingular and can be used to nullify the blocks above each copy. We have the following row equivalence
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
B_0 & B_1 &     &     &     \\
    & -I & B_2 &     &     \\
    &     & -I & B_3 &     \\
    &     &     & -I & B_4 \\
D   &     &     &     & -I \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\sim 
\begin{pmatrix}
B_0 & B_1 &     &     &     \\
    & -I & B_2 &     &     \\
    &     & -I & B_3 &     \\
B_4D    &     &     & -I &  \\
D   &     &     &     & -I \\
\end{pmatrix} \sim
\begin{pmatrix}
B_0 & B_1 &     &     &     \\
    & -I & B_2 &     &     \\
B_3B_4D    &     & -I & &     \\
B_4D    &     &     & -I &  \\
D   &     &     &     & -I \\
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
B_0 & B_1 &     &     &     \\
B_2B_3B_4D    & -I &  &     &     \\
B_3B_4D    &     & -I &   &     \\
B_4D    &     &     & -I &  \\
D   &     &     &     & -I \\
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
B_0+B_1B_2B_3B_4D &  &     &     &     \\
B_2B_3B_4D    & -I &  &     &     \\
B_3B_4D    &     & -I &  &     \\
B_4D    &     &     & -I &  \\
D   &     &     &     & -I \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
You can now factor the block $B_0 + B_1B_2B_3B_4D$ and compute $x_0$. The rest will be just be forward substitution, but compute them in descending order $x_4$, $x_3$, $x_2$, $x_1$ so that you do not have to regenerate the spike on the left.

Answer (score 3):

You could try formulating it as a feasibility optimization problem such as
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rrclcl}
\displaystyle \min_{x} &0 \\
\textrm{s.t.} & A x & = & b \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}$$

and feed it into a linear programming solver based on a branch-and-price algorithm such as [GCG](https://gcg.or.rwth-aachen.de/#about). Such algorithms are usually designed to exploit structured variables via a [Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dantzig%E2%80%93Wolfe_decomposition). In fact, GCG is a branch-price-and-cut solver, meaning it also adds cutting planes in addition to the column generation approach via DW-decomposition. Very often such structured problems like yours can be solved fast via such a decomposition algorithm.

In the above problem formulation you can use any objective function as you are only looking for a feasible solution of your system $Ax=b$. Technically, you could replace the 0-objective function with any other objective function but why not just keep it simple?

Comment: I'll try this approach and will give an update once some results are there (expected at the end of next week).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest quite fast way is probably to use Carl-Christians algebraic solution.

If you are interested in low-level calculational tricks for these matrices you can keep reading below line.

---

Given the matrix structure there are some key matrix elements at the tips of the triangles. If you let the solution diffuse from there as in forward-substitution-like scheme or implicitly with CG you will gain a lot.

Maybe you can get some inspiration from another question of mine, if I can find it. Any triangular matrix you can factor into sparse di-diagonal matrix "in-place" multiplication. This saves calculations. But I don't remember where I wrote this question right now so I will try explain.

You can factor:
$$B_i = F_1F_2\cdots F_m$$

Where each $F_i$ is an identity matrix except for the entries (i,i) and (i,i+1) which need to be determined.

Whooops $m$ matrices you think, but $m$ is huge, but since we only need store 2 values for each, it will only need $2m$ in total for each $B_i$, compared to $m^2/2$ which the tridiagonal $B_i$ ones need.

In practice for $m=10^5$ you could reduce memory fingerprint from tens gigabytes to singles of megabytes.

Comment: How do you propose to obtain and apply the many factorization into products of bidiagonal matrices using level-3 BLAS operations?